# MongoDB project updated record in a nested array in "findAndModify" query

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to find a record in a nested array, modify it, and then project it.

Let's say I have the following collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56558dfc45a06f51decb4ab7"),
    "arr" : [ 
        {
            "cond" : 1.0000000000000000,
            "upd" : 2.0000000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "cond" : 2.0000000000000000,
            "upd" : 3.0000000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "cond" : 4.0000000000000000,
            "upd" : 5.0000000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "cond" : 6.0000000000000000,
            "upd" : 7.0000000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "cond" : 8.0000000000000000,
            "upd" : 9.0000000000000000
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find the record where "cond=4", update it to "upd=55" and return the record.

I've tried the following query:

```
db.tests.findAndModify({
    query:{
        "arr": {"$elemMatch": {"cond":4}}
    },
    update: {
        "$set": {"arr.$": {"cond": 4, "upd": 55, "new": true}}
    },
    fields: {"arr.$":1}
})
```

It performs the update well, but I receive the following result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56558dfc45a06f51decb4ab7"),
    "arr" : [ 
        {}, 
        {}, 
        {}, 
        {}, 
        {}
    ]
}
```

*I'm using MongoDB version :3.0.7

Comment: along with updating "upd": 55, you are adding new field "new": true. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try the **[`positional $`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** operator used with the **[`findAndModify()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db.collection.findAndModify)** method. The operator will identify the element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array. Note, the array field must appear as part of the query document and to return the document with the modifications made on the update, use the new option, so your update would be like

```
db.tests.findAndModify({
    query: {
        "arr.cond": 4
    },
    update: {
        "$set": {"arr.$.upd": 55 }
    },
    new : true,
    fields: { "arr": 1, "_id": 0 }   
})
```

will produce the ouput:

```
{
    "arr": [
        {
            "cond" : 1,
            "upd" : 2
        },
        {
            "cond" : 2,
            "upd" : 3
        },
        {
            "cond" : 4,
            "upd" : 55
        },
        {
            "cond" : 6,
            "upd" : 7
        },
        {
            "cond" : 8,
            "upd" : 9
        }
    ]
}
```

Since you want to return the updated document, with projection the positional **[`$ projection`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_)** operator can only be used in the projection document of the `find()` method or the `findOne()` method so the **[`findAndModify()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db.collection.findAndModify)**'s **`field`** option will not project that part of the array using the  **[`$ projection`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_)** operator.

A workaround would be to use the native JavaScript **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method on the returned arr field as

```
var result = db.tests.findAndModify({
    query: {
        "arr.cond": 4
    },
    update: {
        "$set": {"arr.$.upd": 55 }
    },
    new : true,
    fields: { "arr": 1, "_id": 0 }   
})

var updated = []
if (result && result.arr) updated = result.arr.filter(function (item) { return item.cond == 4; });
printjson(updated);
```

This will print

```
[ { "cond" : 4, "upd" : 55 } ]
```

-- **UPDATE** --

Or the **[`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)** projection as you suggested in the comments below:

```
var result = db.tests.findAndModify({
    query: {
        "arr.cond": 4
    },
    update: {
        "$set": {"arr.$.upd": 55 }
    },
    new : true,
    fields: {"arr": {"$elemMatch": { "cond": 4 } }, "_id": 0 }   
})

printjson(result);
```

**Output**:

```
{ "arr" : [ { "cond" : 4, "upd" : 55 } ] }
```

Comment: In this case I can just use : `fields: {"arr": {"$elemMatch": {"cond":4}}}`. But that means that the mongo engine will perform another filter instead of using the index it has.

Comment: @skme Good call though not too sure about mongo performing another filter with the `$elemMatch` projection.

Comment: This seems to be a too specific solution in case someone would like to update certain nested fields to a single value. But how is it possible to update an entire objected that is nested inside an array?