# MongoDB | Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a scheme with nested arrays. I want to push an element to the 2rd dimension array.
How can I do?

```
//working
db.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.params._universtiyid,'faculties._id':req.params._facultiesid},
    { $push:
        {  'faculties.$.points':point}},


//not working
db.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.params._universtiyid,'faculties._id':req.params._facultiesid},
    { $push:
        {  'faculties.$.department.$.points':points}},

//schema
faculties:[
        {   
            name:{type:String},
            department:[
                {
                    name:{type:String},
                    points:[]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```

Comment: You can only use $ once. One way potentially of achieving what you want is to overwrite the entire second array using aggregation pipeline update operators and $out/$merge.

Comment: @D.SM Thanks for quick response. Can you write a little sample code for me?

Comment: you can do this way using arrayFilters https://stackoverflow.com/a/63041332/8987128

Comment: @turivishal its working thanks. I've been working for a day, you solved it in 2 minutes. I'm grateful.

Comment: yup it is easy to use and ready-mate for nested array..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return the element I'm looking for inside a nested array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62988071/how-can-i-return-the-element-im-looking-for-inside-a-nested-array)